# python2 lambda syntax error with three-tuple argument in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I'm getting a `SyntaxError` using a lambda with a three-tuple

```
candidates = [' '.join(word for word, pos, chunk in group).lower()
              for key, group in itertools.groupby(all_chunks, lambda (word,pos,chunk): chunk != 'O') if key]
```

where `all_chunks` is a `list`.

the error is

```
 for key, group in itertools.groupby(all_chunks, lambda (word,pos,chunk): chunk != 'O') if key]
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

That syntax is valid in Python2, but not in Python3.
The tuple is a three-tuple, otherwise getting a `TypeError` error

```
     13     # join constituent chunk words into a single chunked phrase
---> 14     candidates = [' '.join(word for word, pos, chunk in group).lower()
     15                   for key, group in itertools.groupby(all_chunks, lambda word,pos,chunk: chunk != 'O') if key]
     16 

TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'pos' and 'chunk'
```

Comment: Try `lambda woPoCh: woPoCh[2] != 'O')` . Also know that you need to sort `all_chunk` but the SAME KEY you use for the groupby or it won't work

Comment: this is one of my least favourite things about python 3, this worked in python 2

Comment: @azro I think now this is related to Python2 / Python3. To syntax is ok in Python2, not in Python3. Why?

Comment: Because python3 is not python2, theyr changed that's it

Comment: yes just updated the question to be more specific about the right python3 syntax.

Comment: According to the language's [grammer](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) the same rules as function definitions apply to lambdas. So it is just like you will not do `def foo(a, (b,c), d):`. Either take 3 arguments, or one argument and unpack it inside the lambda

Comment: What is `group` ?

Comment: @Tomerikoo okay so this syntax was still valid in Python2 and changed in Python3?

Comment: Apparently... @nakE it is the value returned by `groupby`

Comment: Note: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga could it be still possible to unpack using the `*` splash as `Extended Iterable Unpacking`? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/

Comment: @loretoparisi sure, but not in the parameters, and that would have to be a statement, which can't be part of a lambda

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok thanks how to apply in this case? I'm not sure if I must explicitly expand all the for loop here and use a named function instead of a lambda then...

Comment: Well, you an just use `lambda triple: triple[2] != '0'`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga right, there's no need to expand the tuple actually! Please answer so I can accept.